# Why does my Bootstrap dropdown open on the left side of the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

See here: http://codepen.io/leftynaut/pen/PPNLEL

Not sure why my dropdown opens on the left side of the page.

Am I doing a centered single-column layout incorrectly?

```
<div class="container text-center">
<div class="row top5"></div>
<div class="row">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the btn-group class before the dropdown class in the wrapping div, then your menu will be positioned correctly.

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose an account  <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Free Code Camp</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```